Is there an ODE so that every solution is extensible?
The following question arose while studying initial value problems of ODE with the form: \begin{align*}y'(t)&=f(t,y(t)),\\ y(t_0)&=y_0.\end{align*} A solution to an IVP above is a function $u:J\to \Omega$, where $J$ is an open interval and $\Omega\subseteq\mathbb{R}^n$ is an open set, which satisfies our IVP above. An extension is a solution to our IVP, $\overline{u}:\overline{J}\to\Omega$ where $\overline{J}$ is a bigger interval, $u=\overline{u}$ in $J$.
We know that if $u$ is not extensible, then $u$ is either a global solution, $u(J)$ gets arbitrarily close to the boundary of $\Omega$ or $u$ has an asymptote at one of the boundary points of $J$.
Now if $f$ is locally Lipschitz continuous, we know that there exists a non-extensible solution. If $f$ is only continuous however, we only know that there exists a local solution for some $J$.
Question: Now do the above conditions imply a non-extensible solution for a non Lipschitz but continuous $f$?
If a solution is neither global, gets arbitrarily close to the boundary of $\Omega$ or has an asymptote, the contraposition of the above Theorem states that it should be extensible. The proof provided for the existence of a non-extensible solution if $f$ is Lipschitz does not work for continuous functions and I'm wondering if there is a counter example to an analogous statement.

Just a passerby who cannot understand the question: (i) "Now if $f$ is locally Lipschitz continuous we know, that there exists a non extensible solution." This appears not to be true; is that really what was meant? (ii) "If $f$ is only continuous however, we only know, that there exists a local solution for some $J$." Is this meant to be in contrast to point (i)? (iii) "Now do the above conditions imply a non-extensible solution for a non Lipschitz but continuous $f$?" Which above conditions? Locally Lipschitz? Continuous? Something else? Can you please reword to clarify?

to i), yes that's what I meant, with $f$ being locally Lipschitz continuous regarding the second variable. (ii) yes this is meant to be different from point (i), as for continuous functions, we only know of local Existence a priori, while for Lipschitz continuous we know of a local solution, which is non extensible. (iii) Sorry if this wasn't clear, I meant if we can get a similar statement to (i) for only continuous functions, which may not be locally Lipschitz.

You are difficult to understand. Any solution is continuously differentiable, which implies locally Lipschitz. If $f(t,y)$ is t-uniformly bounded in $y$ by a constant or linear function, then any solution can be extended. If the ODE is linear in $y$ with continuous coefficients, then solutions can be maximally extended in time. Other statements of this kind exist. But if $f$ is only locally Lipschitz in $y$ does not imply that there must be some solution with a pole at finite time. There are just examples for this behavior.
